# Time always 0 in a go program

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying here to get trades from Bitfinex API and print them on the screen. Everything works fine, except for times.

I wonder why they always prints as 0001-01-01 00:00:00 in this example...

In UnmarshalJSON, "t" contains the time I need. It just doesn't seem to stick to the Trade structure.

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "net/http"
        "strconv"
        "time"
)

type Trade struct {
        Tid       int
        Timestamp myTime
}

type myTime time.Time

func (t myTime) String() string {
        when := time.Time(t)
        return when.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
}

func (t myTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
        ts, err := strconv.Atoi(string(b))
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        t = myTime(time.Unix(int64(ts), 0))

        return nil
}

func main() {
        trades, _ := GetTrades()

        for _, trade := range trades {
                fmt.Printf("%d - %s\n", trade.Tid, trade.Timestamp)
        }
}

func GetTrades() (trades []Trade, err error) {
        r, err := http.Get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD")
        defer r.Body.Close()

        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        json.Unmarshal(body, &trades)

        return
}
```

Comment: does exporting myTrade work? (name it `MyTrade`) also can you post an example json? https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD returns `[]`

Comment: Is `Format` not converting the time to a string? Should you not use a proper formatting?

Comment: You can get the JSON directly from that URL, just like the program: https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD

Comment: The formatting is done in the String() method.

Comment: If I printf the t variable in the UnmarshalJSON method, it prints correctly. It just doesn't in the main method.

Comment: If you want to test the program, just paste it in a program.go file and do "go run program.go" in command line... It contains everyting needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unmarshal on a pointer receiver .. otherwise you're just copying unrelated data around:

```
func (t *myTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    //  ^^^^^^^ this
    ts, err := strconv.Atoi(string(b))
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }

    *t = myTime(time.Unix(int64(ts), 0))
 // ^^ this too

    return nil
}
```

I'm not sure how "safe"/"idiomatic" this is to re-assign data in a pointer receiver.. can someone clarify?

(this works btw.. not sure if its "best practice")

Comment: It works fine and it's a proper practice, check my answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign in `UnmarshalJSON` to a value, you have to use a pointer or a struct, one approach is:

```
type MyTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t MyTime) String() string {
    when := time.Time(t.Time)
    return when.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
}

func (t *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    ts, err := strconv.Atoi(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    t.Time = time.Unix(int64(ts), 0)

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I agree, but it's a bit less obvious for the end user when outputting a struct containing a single property. I prefer returning time directly in that context. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: @RooSoft glad to be of help, also keep in mind that using embedding allows you to use time.Time's methods on myTime directly.